# why beforeRouteUpdate is not updating route

Tags: vue.js, router

I am showing the products page use vueJS and API.
I am showing categories on the left side and products on the right side
but while clicking on category products should be shown and the same component should be a load but the same component is not loading
Please check why beforeRouteUpdate is not working
below is my code

```
     <template>
     <div style="padding: 25px">

     <div class="container">
     <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="row">
                <h3>Categories</h3>
                <div class="col-md-12" align="left">
                    <router-link type="button" align="left" class="card-link" :to="'/'">
                        All Products</router-link>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12" v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id">
                    <CategoryCard :category="category" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <h1 class="index-msg">
                {{ msg }}
            </h1>
            <div v-if="isShowId">
                <span>props id:{{id}}</span>
                <br />
                <span>route.params id: {{uid}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4" v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
                    <ProductCard :product="product" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
   </template>

      <script>
      import {
       mapActions,
         mapGetters
       } from "vuex";
       import CategoryCard from "../../components/products/CategoryCard";
        import ProductCard from "../../components/products/ProductCard";

       export default {
         name: "Products",
          props: ["id"],
            computed: {
              ...mapGetters("product", ["products"]),
             ...mapGetters("category", ["categories"]),
                 },
         components: {
             ProductCard,
              CategoryCard,
             },
       data() {
    return {
        msg: "Products Page",
        uid: "",
        isShowId: false,
    };
   }, 
       methods: {
    ...mapActions("product", ["getProducts", "addCart", "removeCart"]),
    ...mapActions("category", ["getCategories"]),
     },

 mounted() {
    let id = this.$route.params.id;
    if (id) {
        this.isShowId = true;
        this.uid = id;
        
    } else {
        this.isShowId = false;
        this.uid = "";
       
    }
    this.getProducts(id);
    this.getCategories();
},

   beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
           next();
    },
  beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
    console.log(`Leave to =`, to);
    console.log(`Leave from =`, from);
     next();
   },

 };
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check what's the 'pathPre' variable here. This will help you finding where to route now.

```
beforeRouteUpdate: function (to, from, next) {
    let pathPre = from.path.split("/");
    console.log(pathPre)
    next();
  },
```

And if you want to just reload the route on the same url then use

```
this.$router.go();
```

**Edited**
Load with variable as slug
Try to use slug with route

```
{
    path: '/routeA/:slug',
    name: 'routeName',
    component: routeA,
    props:true,
}
```

and push to url with **slug** and **route name**

```
this.$router.push({
          name: "routeName",
          params: { slug: passSlugVariable },
        });
```

and catch this prop in data as variable

```
data: function () {
    return {
      slug: this.$route.params.slug,
    };
 }
```

Comment: this.$router.go();  this cannot work as I am loading the same component with a different variable

Comment: Try to use slug with route
`{
    path: '/routeA/:slug',
    name: 'routeA',
    component: routeA,

}`

Comment: @Rashmeet Edited the awnser. If you need any info on this, you can ask

Comment: { path: 'products/:id',props: true,name:'Products',  component: () => import('../views/home/Products.vue') },

data() {
        return {
            msg: "Products Page",
            slug: this.$route.params.slug,
           };
    },




beforeRouteUpdate: function (to, from, next) {
    let pathPre = from.path.split("/");
    console.log(pathPre);
    this.$router.push({
          name: "Products",
          params: { slug: to.path },
        });
    next();
  },

Comment: still i am not able to reload components

Comment: Please check watch method in the above post

Answer (score 0):

```
  watch: {
      '$route'(to, from) {
          let to_path = to.path;
          let from_path = from.path;
          console.log(`to =`, to_path);
          console.log(`from =`, from_path);
          if (to_path !== from_path) {
              this.$router.push(to_path)
             
               this.$router.go();
          } else {
             
              this.$router.go();
           }

          },
      },
```

This is working as I am refreshing the page every time using this.$router.go(); , I know this is wrong method , please tell me correct solution